# "Dirty" .htaccess file?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Heads up - I am a rather inexperienced techy, but certainly more technical than my companions! We have a WordPress site, and have installed/removed various plugins.

The reason for this post is that we're suffering significant wait/TTFB issues on our website. The site is hosted on an Apache VPS, and I read that the .htaccess file can be problematic for such setups.

Any advice/guidance will be greatly appreciated! We wanted to really just check that our .htaccess file looks "Ok"? To the untrained eye it looks like there is some repetition towards the bottom, and there is also the statement "AddType x-httpd-php54 .php" - which I wanted to make sure was necessary at this level. The .htaccess file is stored in the public_html folder.

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/example\.com\/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp_woocommerce_session).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(iphone|midp|sony|symbos|nokia|samsung|mobile|epoc|ericsson|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-|portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc|android|blackberry|playbook|ipad|ipod|iemobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile|bb10|xoom|p160u|nexus|touch|SCH-I800|opera\smini|SM-G900R4|LG-|HTC|GT-I9505|WAP-Browser|Nokia309|Casper_VIA).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /var/sites/b/example.com/public_html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache
# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=2592000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
#Gzip AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript #End Gzip
AddType x-httpd-php54 .php
```

Comment: Moving from Apache to NGINX would be a permanent solution..

Comment: You can definitely remove that repeated `# BEGIN WordPress....# END WordPress` section. The `x-httpd-php54` is used to select PHP 5.4 (assuming you have more than one version available). If you have a later version than 5.4 on your server, you should use that instead - if it is the default version, you could remove that line.

Comment: Downvoted becuase of the 'off-topic' flag. Fair point by the mods and these kind of questions usually get upvotes over time. Cheers, Crowie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this `.htaccess` file. Except the repetition of Wordpress Dispatcher at the end:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You could remove one of those. But this will change nothing in Apache performance. The first rules are catches first and the second ones never reached.

There other rules are only setting cache management, cache expires headers and compression.

Concerning the `AddType x-httpd-php54 .php`, you're setting the `PHP` version to be used with your website. You could try to use an higher version if available with your hosting and see if there's no compatibility error.

Comment: Thank you Florian, I have removed the repetition of the Wordpress Dispatcher. Now to create a ticket to try and solve my performance issues once and for all!